# Time and Space Complexity of a complex while statement

Tags: c, time-complexity

```
int foo(char *str)
{
    char *p = str;
    while (p && *p!='\0' && 
        ((*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z') 
            || (*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z') || *p == '@')) {
         p++;
    }
    return p-str;
}
```

What will be the time and space complexity of the above complex `while` statement. Does it depends on no of statements in the while en-closer 
 `while (p && *p!='\0' && ((*p >= 'a' && *p <= 'z') || (*p >= 'A' && *p <= 'Z') || *p == '@'))`

or only on `while` body

```
while(){ 
 //body statements   
  p++;
}
```

as above. Also does it depends on short-circuiting of `&&` or `||` .

Comment: If I were you, I'd worry less about performance and more about readability :-) And possibly portability - not _everyone_ uses ASCII.

Comment: @paxdiablo Not true - not everyone uses ASCII :-) and why do you think he does not - for example EBCDIC guarantees the >= <= for values

Comment: The mainframe (z/OS) uses EBCDIC, even for their UNIX subsystem. And A-Z are _not_ contiguous in EBCDIC. The ISO C standard only guarantees contiguity (??) for the `0-9` range.

Comment: Right so char='A' <= char='Z' in EBCDIC in C - which was the posters language. C standard rules over platform. The C standard guarantees such comparisons.

Comment: @yogeshrl the big thing is the while loop itself... as the input increases in size `N`, the time `T(N)` is asymptotically upper-bounded by `kN` and thus its runtime is `O(N)`.

Comment: The C standard only guarantees that 0 < 1 < 2... < 9 and that their symbol table values are adjacent. See C11 5.2.1/3. No other guarantees about character comparisons are made by the standard.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about your runtime or space complexity, but the actual condition complexity can be simplified quite lot to make it more readable. First of all you don't have to check the pointer `p` every loop, check that `str` is a non-null pointer in a separate check first. Secondly you should use [`isalpha`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/isalpha) to check for letters.

So the code could look like this instead:

```
int foo(char *str)
{
    if (str == NULL)
        return 0;

    char *p = str;
    while (*p != '\0' && (isalpha(*p) || *p == '@'))
        p++;

    return p - str;
}
```

Using `isalpha` helps you with those problems noted in the comments to your question, and also works even if your locale is changed.

Answer (score 0):

When you talk about complexity, you're talking about how much it grows based upon the size of the input.  In this case, it's based on the size of the string passed in as `str`.  The number of stuff being checked for in the while condition does not change.  It is fixed into the algorithm, what is called a "constant factor," so we don't count it.  Since in the worst case the test is run on each character of the string once, it is `O(n)`, where `n` is the length of the string.